# How to reload a div without reloading the entire page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, reload

I suppose what I am asking is really easy for most of you. I want to reload a div without reloading the entire page. What's the best way to do it?

```
<div class="black_text" id="cp_in_content_div">
<?php
$id = $_GET["id"];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Setting WHERE ID = $id");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
switch ($_GET["action"])
{
    case "delete":
    if (!unlink("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]setting/$row[Filename]"))
    {
        echo "Error.";
        header("Refresh: 2.5; URL=delete_setting.php?id=$id");
        exit();
    }
    if (!mysql_query("DELETE FROM Setting WHERE ID = $id"))
    {
        echo "Error.";
        header("Refresh: 2.5; URL=delete_setting.php?id=$id");
        exit();
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Ok!";
        header("Refresh: 1.25; URL=index.php");
    }
    break;
    default:
    echo "form";
}
?>
</div>
```

I need those header("Refresh:...") to only reload the div instead of the page.

Comment: Welcome to SO @Gabriele!  Can you edit the question to provide the code that you are working on ?

Comment: @jas:I feel he has got no code :)

Answer (score 26):

[jQuery.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) is probably the easiest way to load data asynchronously using a selector, but you can also use any of the jquery ajax methods (get, post, getJSON, ajax, etc.)

Note that load allows you to use a selector to specify what piece of the loaded script you want to load, as in

```
$("#mydiv").load(location.href + " #mydiv");
```

Note that this technically does load the whole page and jquery removes everything but what you have selected, but that's all done internally.

Comment: How do I show a "loader.gif" until entire div is not loaded. Because my div is very huge and coming from a file. So it takes about 2 seconds.
How to I show something like `loading...` until jquery completes the task.

Comment: is there an option to load by tag not by id !?

Comment: @Yasmine you can use any valid selector, even `$("div").load` should work, but keep in mind that this will select _all_ divs on the page and trigger the load

Answer (score 8):

```
$("#div_element").load('script.php');
```

demo: http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/2ecbe/3

whole code:

```
<div id="submit">ajax</div> 
<div id="div_element"></div> 
<script> 
$('#submit').click(function(event){ 
   $("#div_element").load('script.php?html=some_arguments');  

}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

Use this.

```
$('#mydiv').load(document.URL +  ' #mydiv');
```

Note, include a space before the hastag.

Comment: can i call it with tag instead of id !!?

Answer (score 1):

write a button tag and on click function

```
var x = document.getElementById('codeRefer').innerHTML;
  document.getElementById('codeRefer').innerHTML = x;
```

write this all in onclick function

Comment: hi, I tried this for updating a table. but it seems like the table is still the same as before. No update in the table data, even though new data is added to the table. @Ambala Chandrashekar