# How to update form data without using button and refresh page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I have create an edit form where I want to update only assets form field. Here, I am using keyup function of jQuery through which I want to update my assets form field value without refreshing page and button. But now only single row value has been updated right now and I have multiple row. it always update first row data. So, How can I fix this problem ? Please help me.

controller: test.php

```
public function update_assets()
{
    $data = array(
                'assets_id'=> $this->input->post('assets'),
                );
    $where = "admin_id = '".$this->input->post('admin_id')."' and inventory_id = '".$this->input->post('inventory_id')."'";
    $this->db->where($where);
    $this->db->update('inventory',$data);
    echo $this->db->last_query();
}
```

view:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".assets").keyup(function(){
            inventory_id = $("#inventory_id").val();
            assets = $("#assets"+inventory_id).val();
            admin_id = $("#admin_id").val();
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                data:{"assets":assets, "admin_id":admin_id, "inventory_id":inventory_id},
                url:"<?php echo base_url('index.php'); ?>/test/update_assets",
                success:function(data){
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<input type="hidden" name="admin_id" id="admin_id" value="<?php echo $logg; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="inventory_id" id="inventory_id" value="<?php echo $inventory_id; ?>">
<input type="text" name="assets" id="assets<?php echo $inventory_id; ?>" />
```

Thank You

Comment: the `hidden input` you mention in question also repeat ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175038/how-to-reload-a-div-without-reloading-the-entire-page

Comment: but the name & id is different @urfusion

Comment: Ok, What about Ids?